# React updating Like counter when user clicks like button without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

> This is my parent component that renders my **Like Component**. The parent component has a state called **Likes** that stores all the **Likes**. The **handleLike** function gets called from the **Like** component. **likeFood(foodId, UserId)** is my api call that creates a new like for specific post that i have in a separate file.

```
   // this is my api 
   export default function likeFood(foodId, UserId) {
  
  Axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_APIENDPOINT}/Likes/like`, {
  foodId: foodId,
   UserId: UserId,
  }).catch(function (error) {
   console.log(error);
  });
   }

  // this handleLike function gets called from the child Like component and should also handle updating the state.

  handleLike = async (foodId, UserId) => {
  const oldLikes = this.state.Likes;
   const newLikes = oldLikes.filter((like) => like.foodId === foodId);
   likeFood(foodId, UserId);
   this.setState({ Likes: newLikes });
  };
```

> Note if i change const newLikes = oldLikes.filter((like) => **like.foodId === foodId**);

to

> const newLikes = oldLikes.filter((like) => **like.foodId !== foodId**);

the state updates properly when disliking but not when liking.

```
     // here i render my Like component
     <Like
      foodId={food.id}
      UserId={id}
      Likes={this.state.Likes}
      handleLike={this.handleLike}
     />
```

> This is my Like component

```
     function Like({ foodId, UserId, Likes, handleLike }) {

     // this function calculates the amount of likes for each specific post
     function likeAmount(foodId) {
           const likes = Likes.filter((like) => like.foodId === foodId);
        return likes.length;
        }

      return (

<div className="like-button">
  <BsHeart
    className="like"
    size={24}
    onClick={() => handleLike(foodId, UserId)}
  />
  <p>{likeAmount(foodId)}</p>
</div>
);
}

 export default Like;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change liking method.

```
handleLike = async (foodId, UserId) => {
  const oldLikes = this.state.Likes;
   const newLikes = [...oldLikes, {foodId: foodId}]; // Define your object
   likeFood(foodId, UserId);
   this.setState({ Likes: newLikes });
  };
```